# Passing Dataframe column as variable to a dict in a loop

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe with 2 columns as below:

```
name, type
prod_a, fruit
prod_b, vegetable
prod_c, fruit
```

I am trying to pass these two columns to the below dict in a loop:

```
data = {"name": df['name'],
        "accountId": df['type']}
```

How could I pass values from the Dataframe into the above dict `data`

Comment: What is expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want loop by each row and create dictionaries separately use:

```
for x, y in df[['name','type']].values:
    data = {"name": x, "accountId": y}

    print (data)
{'name': 'prod_a', 'accountId': 'fruit'}
{'name': 'prod_b', 'accountId': 'vegetable'}
{'name': 'prod_c', 'accountId': 'fruit'}
```

Or rename column and use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `r` for method `records`:

```
for data in df[['name','type']].rename(columns={'type':'accountId'}).to_dict('r'):
    print (data)
{'name': 'prod_a', 'accountId': 'fruit'}
{'name': 'prod_b', 'accountId': 'vegetable'}
{'name': 'prod_c', 'accountId': 'fruit'}
```

If need same output use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `l` for method `list`:

```
data = df[['name','type']].rename(columns={'type':'accountId'}).to_dict('l')
print (data)
{'name': ['prod_a', 'prod_b', 'prod_c'], 
 'accountId': ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'fruit']}
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['prod_a', 'prod_b', 'prod_c'],
    'type': ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'fruit']
})

data = dict()

for i in list(df.columns):
    data.update({('accountId' if i=='type' else i): list(df[i])})
```

---

```
print(data)
{'name': ['prod_a', 'prod_b', 'prod_c'],
 'accountId': ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'fruit']}
```